# How to return a HashMap within a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to return the first inner HashMap of the outer HashMap, but this method I am using does not work.

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getMap(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> allQs) {
    HashMap <String, Integer> value = allQs.getValue();
    return value;
}
```

How can I return the object as a HashMap?

Comment: *"the inner HashMap that is the value of the outer HashMap"* => No. `allQs` has (potentially) many values. Which one is *the value*?

Comment: @ernest_k I changed the framing of the question. I am simply trying to retrieve the inner HashMap!

Comment: Exactly. There are potentially many inner hash maps (or none). Which one are you supposed to return?

Comment: @ernest_k There is only one inner HashMap because I made it that way. But if there were many, I need the first one.

Comment: Well, you can try `return allQs.values().iterator().next();` but if the map has many inner maps, then that will return **any** (not **first**) - and that will only work if the map is not empty

Comment: If your map will always have only one inner map then you are probably misusing maps. Instead it looks like you should create your own class (at least for outer map) which will store inner map as field.

Comment: So you want to iterate all values, check for their type (if it is a hashmap or not) and return the matching one? That's terrible. Also conflicts with the generic type `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>` which states that there can be no other values than HashMaps.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the advice, creating a new class did not occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: HashMap does not maintain the insertions order if order matters then use LinkedHashMap.

And also Hashmap does not have any method `getValue()`;

If you want to get the first value then use

```
for(HashMap<String,Integer> innerMap : map.values())
{
    return innerMap;
}
```

or

```
map.values().stream().findFirst().get()
```

Comment: But you have no control over what that "first" value will be in case there are many. And in case the map is empty it will error out. And if you have only a single entry in the map, or no meaningful keys at all, why is this a map in the first place?

Comment: If it's a linked Hashmap you get the value in the insertion order.
The first logic works fine for the empty map but for using stream way, you have to ensure about map being non-empty.
And the last one is a different question about implementation and we cannot comment about it without knowing one's use-case.